# jQuery wrapAll category-1, category-2, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wrapall

I'd like to be able to wrap multiple elements with the same class (for instance category-1) within a parent element. I know this can be done with `jQuery wrapAll()`. No problem there. 
But what I want to be able to do is wrap all elements with class `"category-X"`, where X is a number of my own choice.
Do I create an array? Or how do I go about?

Comment: Don't understand. Need more info.

Comment: What prevents you from calling `wrapAll()` on all elements with class `category-4` or `category-7` or any number you need?

Comment: Can you put a snippet of code to elaborate more of what are you trying to do.

Comment: I'd like to be able to find all elements with category-1, wrap them in a container (container-1). And then find the next elements with category-2, wrap them in another container (container-2), and so on. I'd like to be able to do so without having to write specific code for each "category-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility, not as simple as calling `wrapAll()`, is:

```
$('[class^="category-"]').each(function(){
    var n = this.className.replace('category-',''),
        container = $('.container-' + n).length ? $('.container-' + n) : $('<div />', {
            'class' : 'container-' + n
        }).appendTo(this.parentNode);
    $(this).appendTo(container);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Thu89/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Yes, that seems to work, however, I like this better, fits my needs better:

http://jsfiddle.net/orjan/psSY5/

(Worked a bit on C-link's solution).

The only thing that I'm missing here is NOT setting an amount.

Comment: So let the script determine the length: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/psSY5/4/).

Comment: Much better! :D
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, wrapAll() methods wraps all the categories you need to use just wrap() method:

```
var num = 10; //specify how many here ???
for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
    $('.category').wrap('<div class="category-' + i + '" />');
}
```

Comment: No, that's not really what I want. Sorry if I'm being fuzzy.
Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/orjan/gVDPe/